# Integrating Chessboard.js in meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor, chess, chessboard.js

I am using meteor, which I am new to, for my current project and want to replace the current chessboard I made with that from chessboardjs.com and was hoping some one may have experience with this. I downloaded the files from the website, put the css files in a css directory I created and the images in my public/image directory but was wondering where to place the .js files. I am not used to working with multiple files in meteor. I am creating a client and server directory. Should I just place the .js files in the client directory? Also, on the site it says to get started add

to the javascript
var board1 = new ChessBoard('board1', 'start');
and to the html

Could some one suggest a way to use meteor templates to put this in the .js files? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Are you working with an aspx file?

Answer (score 2):

You should place external client libraries somewhere in `/client` folder. Usually it's either `/client/lib` to ensure they're loaded before the rest of your code, or `/client/compatibility` to ensure they work even if they aren't designed to work with Meteor, or `/client/lib/compatibility` for both.

Comment: Thanks, and any suggestions on the 2nd part, on how to format the javascript? I am new to the template format on meteor.

Comment: That's a bit broad question. What is your exact problem? What did you try so far? How did it work out?

Comment: Hi, so I tried inserting into the html <div id= {{board1}} style="width: 400px"></div> and into the js Template.TT2.board1 =  function(){var board1 = new ChessBoard('board1', 'start');}};
TT2 is the name of my template. Then when I run it it alerts "the element with Id board1 does not exist in the DOM

Comment: On the chessboard.js website it gives these comments on that error but I am unsure of how to correct this problem: 1002 Element with id "<id>" does not exist in the DOM. 
ChessBoard could not find your element with document.getElementById.

Please note that if you pass a string as the first argument to the ChessBoard() constructor it should be the value of a DOM id, not a CSS selector (ie: "board", not "#board").

Comment: Change the argument form: `<div id="board1" ...>`, then put the `ChessBoard` initialization into `rendered` callback instead of a helper.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I am now adding a button to load a specific position, but the new board does not load when I press the button. THe button works as I tried some alert function. I'm not sure how it works with changing something in the template. Here is my attempt Template.TT2.events = {
'click .setRuyLopezBtn' : function () {
var ruyLopez = 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R';
board1.position(ruyLopez, false);


    }
};